# Showing the devise edit password screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my rails 3 app using devise, I want to provide a link for users to edit their password.

I have a standard link that points to: /users/password/edit ... Log output below

```
Started GET "/users/password/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-10 10:11:46 -0700
  Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 309ms
```

Why is rails redirecting? Why can't I show the edit password page? Thanks

Comment: show your `routes.rb` and `PasswordController`

Comment: What's the reason for the redirect in the flash message?  Is the user not logged in, because yeah, it'll redirect you to root if you're not logged in and trying to edit a password.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Actually the problem is that the user **is** logged in. This action is only for users who are **not** logged in, have forgotten their password, and have already received a reset password token.

Comment: well what does the flash message say?  That edit url should only be valid if there's a valid token parameter attached.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Devise::PasswordsController#edit` is for non-authenticated users who wish to change their password using a reset token. This reset token was previously sent to the user in an email (Reset password instructions). If the user is already logged in, this edit password page will always redirect to the after-sign-in path since it shouldn't be accessible to authenticated users.

I suppose what you want is to allow the user to change his password **after** logging in. You have to use `Devise::RegistrationsController#edit` for that.

Comment: What if I'm using the edit action in the registration controller for other user profile information. I want to separate editing the user profile information (name, address, etc) and the password update

Comment: @Batman https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: If that's true then why is there a view for it? Really confusing.

Comment: Im having this same issue. Following Michael Hartl's Ruby Tutorial on Lesson 12, Im not brought to the reset password form because it keeps redirecting me to the home page! The reason is because "Filter chain halted as :valid user rendered or redirected"