# Override PasswordsController in Devise to change password when the user is already signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I want to add a feature to my app in which when a user is signed in he can change his password just by clicking on change password link.But when I click on that link it redirects to the current page.

```
<%= link_to 'Change password', edit_user_password_path %>
```

Can someone tell me what to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I can't write a comment (my reputation is too low) I'll write an answer instead.

Take a look here:

[rails devise edit_user_password_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859837/rails-devise-edit-user-password-path)

This should solve your problem.

In short: The Devise PasswordsController can only be used if a user is signed_out.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In cases where users can login via omniauth but don't know their password, and want to change their profile (where they need to know their password) this design causes obvious issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming user is loged in and want to change his password

Devise::RegistrationsController#edit

Your link would like:

```
<%= link_to 'Change password', edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
```